# How to write all data from Array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML like :

```
<div id="divid">
  <a href="d#link1">1</a>
    <a href="d#link2">2</a>
    <a href="d#link3">3</a>
    .....................
</div>
```

I have script to get all links from a div like :

```
<script>
    var links = document.getElementById('divid').getElementsByTagName('a') ;
</script>
```

Then I want write link into class like :

```
<script>
        var links = document.getElementById('divid').getElementsByTagName('a') ;
        document.write("<div class="'+link[1]+" "+ link[i]+'">Class is added links</div>");
</script>
```

That mean after write I have HTML:

```
<div class="d#link1 d#link2 d#link3">Classes is added links</div>
```

How can I do this? Using for loop or not? how?

Comment: You're right, use a for loop. It's simple enough, and a google search yields many many results

Comment: [JavaScript for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp). But actually your code is bad practice.

Comment: @mic perhaps you can share with him HOW it is bad practice? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the href property from each element. Put them in an array, and you can just join the strings:

```
var elements = document.getElementById('divid').getElementsByTagName('a');
var links = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  links.push(elements[i].href);
}
document.write("<div class="' + links.join(" ") + '">Class is added links</div>");
```

Comment: Thank you. you are very good. Using join very simple. :). i will remember this.

Comment: Mine is shorter. Still not sure why Guffa down-voted it without leaving a comment.

Comment: @Domi: I didn't downvote your answer. I never downvote without explaining why.

Comment: Sorry. Guffa. Can you check for me again. Something cannot run? It is impossible to join links. check here : http://jsfiddle.net/Luva9/

Comment: @happi: Yes, you are right. That's because it's not an array, it's an HTMLCollection. Create a real array to put the values in. I updated the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Use [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) in combination with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var classString = links.map(function(link) { return link.attributes.href; } ).join(' ');
```

Comment: The downvote was probably because you were joining the elements, as that's what the answer said when you got the downvote. No downvote from me, but note that the `map` method doesn't exist in IE until version 9.

Comment: thanks domi. I highly appreciate your help. vote up for your answer.